# Set local notification sound from Main bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I give a custom sound to local notification, but it is not working.

```
notif.soundName = @"sound.caf";
```

it's play default sound why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don‘t add the sound file (*.caf) in Xcode project: Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources.

Answer (score 1):

I  have done notification successfully with the code below.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if (localNotif == nil)
                return;
            /*  NSDateFormatter *formatDate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
             [formatDate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
             [formatDate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
             NSDate *strDate=[formatDate dateFromString:txtDate.text];
             */
            localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
            //localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

            NSLog(@"the item date is %@",localNotif.fireDate);

            // Notification details
            //localNotif.alertBody = [eventText text];]
            localNotif.alertBody=strEvent;
            // Set the action button
            localNotif.alertAction = @"View";


            //localNotif.soundName = @"Acoustic Noodling 01.caf";
            localNotif.soundName=@"alarm1.aif";
```

Answer (score 0):

About playing custom sounds in Local notifications

**Make sure the sound is actually in your app’s bundle, is in the correct format (linear PCM or IMA4**

Assume that notification is an object of type UILocalNotification.

notification.soundName = @"sound.caf";

If this doesn't work initially then you may refer to this post and there in refer to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170475/choose-custom-sound-for-local-notifications) That tells us to use sound file of the correct format (i.e. either Linear PCM or IMA4).

Answer (score 0):

Just use relative path of your file rather than providing absolute or full path.

For example:

```
localNotification.soundName = @"../Documents/recordedFileName.caf";
```

Also, keep in mind that recordDuration of file should be less than or equal to 29 seconds.

That's it, hope that answered.

Comment: Does this work for you? I have tried it but with no luck