# Option to play a notification sound iOS

Tags: ios, audio, notifications

I wrote an Android application and it had options to choose what system notification sound the user wanted to play for each of the different types of notifications, three in total.

Now I want to write the same application for iOS, but is it possible to do this in iOS, I Googled about this but didn't really find a way on how to do it. Seeing as though iOS 7 is out, have Apple made any changes?

Or is it still restricted, like a million other things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have downloaded the standard iOS 7 alert sounds, and will put them in my bundle, and play them from there. Why does Apple make things so hard?

Answer (score 1):

[Choose custom sound for local notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170475/choose-custom-sound-for-local-notifications)

This link provides the answer. You can find more detail in the apple doc. "In iOS, an application can specify a sound file along with an alert message or badge number.".

Specifically:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Comment: AFAIK there is only one default sound, and if you want to provide more options the sound files should be included in your bundle.

Comment: If you have looked at the settings on an iPhone, under Sound, there is a list of notification sounds and ringtones, right? Now I want to display the SYSTEM notification sounds in my app. Is it possible?

Comment: Alternatively, how I can download the system notifications, so I can put them in my bundle?

Comment: Ok, I have downloaded the standard iOS 7 alert sounds, and will put them in my bundle, and play them from there. Why does Apple make things so hard?