# UILocalNotification no sound alert when screen is lock in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

UILocalNotification does not have the alert sound (the one informing user there is new notification, for remote notification there is sound) when the screen is locked. It displays the icon and alertBody only. I tested it in iOS7. Is there any setting/ configuration can enable the notiification sound ?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330780/uilocalnotification-custom-sound-is-not-playing-in-ios7