# Custom Sound not playing for remote notification on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, apple-push-notifications

Custom sound on my notifications have recently stopped working for my app, after I tried changing the sound file.

My notification payload looks like this.

```
{
"aps" : {
        "alert" : "Your message here.",
        "badge" : 0,
        "sound" : "notification.caf",
        "content-available" : 1
    }
}
```

I've got notification.caf in my application bundle.

I've got code that plays the sound file in other instances, so I note that the sound file is good. It is 29 seconds long, so less than the 30 mandated by Apple.

Under settings->notifications everything is turned on under the app. I've tried testing both when the app is set to Banners and Alerts.

But every time I close down my app, and send a notification from my webservice, the phone just vibrates and shows the notification. No default sound, no custom sound.

I've tested on two different devices, a phone and an ipad, and neither worked. They both run iOS 10.3.1.

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below question. This can be helpful to you.

[UILocalNotification custom sound is not playing in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330780/uilocalnotification-custom-sound-is-not-playing-in-ios7)

Another thing you can try is to add .caf or .mp3 file into ImageAsset and try it.

For some reason in one of my application, I was not able to play custom sound. But after I added .mp3 file into asset folder I was able to play custom sound for remote notification.

Please try code given below.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox
import AVFoundation

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AlarmApplicationDelegate{

    var window: UIWindow?
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    let alarmScheduler: AlarmSchedulerDelegate = Scheduler()
    var alarmModel: Alarms = Alarms()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        var error: NSError?
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch let error1 as NSError{
            error = error1
            print("could not set session. err:\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch let error1 as NSError{
            error = error1
            print("could not active session. err:\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        window?.tintColor = UIColor.red

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        //show an alert window
        let storageController = UIAlertController(title: "Alarm", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        var isSnooze: Bool = false
        var soundName: String = ""
        var index: Int = -1
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            soundName = userInfo["sound"] as! String
        }

        playSound(soundName)

    }

    //print out all registed NSNotification for debug
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

        print(notificationSettings.types.rawValue)
    }

    func playSound(_ soundName: String) {

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate),nil,
                                              nil,
                                              { (_:SystemSoundID, _:UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Void in
                                                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            },
                                              nil)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundName, ofType: "mp3")!)

        var error: NSError?

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            audioPlayer = nil
        }

        if let err = error {
            print("audioPlayer error \(err.localizedDescription)")
            return
        } else {
            audioPlayer!.delegate = self
            audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
        }

        //negative number means loop infinity
        audioPlayer!.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayer!.play()
    }

}
```

I was able to play custom sound for local notification using above call.

This might be helpful to you.

Comment: Well, I'm receiving a remote notification, not creating a local notification. But: "Do not disturb" mode is off. The sound file is formated as caf, and 29 seconds long. And added to the main bundle. And sound is on.

Comment: No, the issue is not resolved, I still receive no sound.

Comment: Can you please update question with code? So we can have more clear idea. Please see updated answer it can be helpful.

Comment: What code do you want? The remote notification is supposed to play the sound when the app is closed (not just in background, but completely closed down). So the only code I have in the app (related to this) is actually signing up for push notifications in the first place.