# iOS alarm clock with music

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I'm trying to build an iOS alarm clock app that plays music when it goes off.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

I've seen various posts from over the years on this topic and it looks like previously this couldn't be done because there was no way to wake up the app to play music.  But I'm wondering if by now there's a way?

For example, can a push notification lead to playback of music?  If not, is there any other way?

Comment: if you meant the notification sound then yes, it can, limited to 30s file for a notification (since it's alarm, probably you want local notification), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170475/choose-custom-sound-for-local-notifications) may help

Comment: I meant using a push notification to wake the app up so it can play music.

Comment: you also can add sound with push notification, you just need to have the music files ready in your app